# ページネーションで、記事のループ処理を最初と最後で違う出力で行う方法がわかりません。

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスでホームページを作成しています。
*初心者で、少し前にPHPに触れたばかりです。また、ダブルポストです。
https://teratail.com/questions/3d01olss0x2g5w
https://qiita.com/keikkkk/questions/7915609d5acb9d3438fc

今現在、アーカイブページで、投稿の一覧のページを作成していて、
プラグインWP-PageNaviを使用し、サイトの最後に
ページネーションを作成しています。

ループ処理の最初と最後で違う出力をすることは出来ていて、
https://on-ze.com/archives/7464
これで行いました。

最初のループと後のループでは、
画像の大きさを変える必要があり、
最初の記事の画像は縦幅が小さく、２番目は大きめです。

プラグインの使用に、
https://senoweb.jp/note/wp-pagenavi-howto/
この内容に取り組みました。

この最初と最後の２つのループ処理とページネーションを同時に使用することが出来ません。

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="blog-archive-wrapper">
    <div class="blog-archive-wrapper-second">
        <div class="blog-archive-outer">    
            <h2 class="blog-archive-outer-title">新着一覧</h2>  
   <div>
    <?php
        $paged = get_query_var('paged')? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $information= new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                ));
        if ( $information ->have_posts() ) :
    ?>
    <ul>    <!-- ループ -->
        <?php while ( $information -> have_posts() ) : $information -> the_post(); ?>  
        <li>

 <?php if ($wp_query->current_post == 0) { ?>                   
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item"></a> 
        <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-content">
        <div class="blog-list-wrapper-second"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image-second"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 148)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  
        <div class="blog-list-category">
         
<?php $cat = get_the_category(); ?>
<?php $cat = $cat[0]; ?>
<p class="blog-list-category-title"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat->term_id); ?></p>
        </div>
              
        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                <?php echo mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 30).'……'; ?>
               </h3>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>     
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php } ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'offset' => 1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

  <div class="blog-list-category">
  <?php $cat = get_the_category(); ?>


<?php $cat = $cat[0]; ?>
<p class="blog-list-category-title"><?php echo get_cat_name($cat->term_id); ?></p>
  </div>
 <div class="blog-list-list-item">
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-item"></a> 

        <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-content-second">
        <div class="blog-list-wrapper"> 
          <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる start ?>    
            <div class="blog-item-thumbnail-second">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <div class="thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(240, 179)); ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php // アイキャッチを表示させる end ?>
        </div>  
              
        <div class="blog-item-content"> 
                 <p class="blog-item-day-second"><?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる start ?>
                <h3 class="blog-item-title">
                <?php echo mb_substr($post->post_title, 0, 30).'……'; ?>
               </h3>
                <?php // タイトルを表示させる end ?>
              <?php // 抜粋を表示させる start ?>
                <p class="blog-item-read">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                </p>
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>     
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div> 
                </li>
               
        </ul>
        <?php
              // サブクエリをリセット
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

<?php
    if( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {
            wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $information));
     }
?>
<?php endif;?>
</div>

 </div>     
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

```
.blog-list-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail-content {
  display: flex;
}
.blog-archive-wrapper {
  width: 70.31953125vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail
  .blog-item-thumbnail-image
  img.attachment-150x110.size-150x110.wp-post-image {
  height: 179px;
  width: 240px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.blog-archive-outer-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4.677vw;
  padding-bottom: 4.6875vw;
}
.img-price-third {
  position: relative;
  height: 221px;
}
img.main-img-third {
  height: 221px;
  width: 100%;
}
.blog-item-content {
  padding-left: 3.90625vw;
}
.blog-item-content .blog-item-day {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #1b224c;
  padding-bottom: 1.40625vw;
}
.blog-item-content .blog-item-title {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5625vw;
}
.blog-item-content p {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}
.blog-item-content p {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail-content {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 7.265625vw;
}
.blog-item-day-second {
  padding-bottom: 1.5625vw;
}
img.attachment-240x148.size-240x148.wp-post-image {
  height: 148px;
  width: 240px;
  object-fit: fill;
  position: relative;
}
img.attachment-240x179.size-240x179.wp-post-image {
  height: 179px;
  width: 240px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
.blog-list-category {
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
  background-color: #1b224c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14.84375vw;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail-content {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 7.265625vw;
  height: 148px;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail-content-second {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 4.765625vw;
}
.blog-item-thumbnail-content-second:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 8.515625vw;
}
.pagination {
  display: flex;
}
h2.screen-reader-text {
  display: none;
}
ul.page-numbers {
  display: flex;
}
ul.page-numbers li {
  width: 3.75vw;
  height: 3.75vw;
  border: 1px solid #1b224c;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.90625vw;
  margin-right: 1.484375vw;
}
ul.page-numbers li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0vw;
}
ul.page-numbers span.page-numbers.current {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.page-numbers li:nth-of-type(4) {
  border: none;
}
span.page-numbers.current {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1b224c;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a.page-numbers {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1b224c;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image: 一番目の記事と２番めの記事の大きさが同じ]
[image: 記事の大きさが違う]

お答えいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 他の質問も含めて、ただ「ダブルポストです」と宣言するだけでは意味がなくて、できれば URL を提示した方が読み手にとって親切だと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ページネーションのコードと、２つのコードを
　https://on-ze.com/archives/7464
を使用し、上手く組み合わせて、なんとか解決できました。